# Is it necessary that the group owner send the connection request?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am currently developing an Android app which includes a feature which requires sending data through a wifi direct connection, my app is riddled with bugs so I just want to know whether it is necessary that the group owner send the connection request because I think it might have something to do with my bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection request is sent by a device which is willing to join the P2P Group (network). If you are asking about P2P Group formation, look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290820/6752997) I tried some explaining.