# BLE Scan on android 8.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.0-oreo, oneplusthree

I've developed an app that do ble scan for nearby devices (multiple kinds of beacons around).
I am scanning using the BluetoothLeScanner with CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES and an empty ScanFilter array (since I want to get callbacks for all nearby devices).

My app was working just fine on my OnePlus 5 device Android 7.x (and few other devices) - until I have upgraded to android 8.0 OTA on my device.

I am not sure if it is Android 8.0 issue or OnePlus Oxygen bug but I face to following situation:
Around me there are many kinds of beacons, some advertise standard ibeacon/eddystone packets and others advertise custom packets.

I receive callbacks (onScanResult) only for the standard ibeacon/eddystone packets and not for the custom ones.
Before upgrading I got the callbacks for all kind of packets - standard and non-standard.

Was something changed in the underline filter of received ble packets in android 8.0?
Is it a bug in latest Oxygen OS version?
Should I add some kind of flag to get non standard packets?

Any idea will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating the packets sent by each beacon, I have figured out that one of the custom beacons sent a packet with wrong data length byte.
That caused the packet to be filtered out by OS 8 (Android OR Oxygen) - did not matter to older versions.

Now i'll have to talk to the firmware company for a fix...

Comment: how did you investigate the packets?

Comment: I have used BLE sniffer